# PHP / Codeigniter - Como converter imagem para array de byte?

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, byte

Eu quero deixar registrado aqui minha solução para este problema.

```
$data = file_get_contents("/ImagePath/Image.jpg");

$array = array(); 

foreach(str_split($data) as $char){ 
   array_push($array, ord($char)); 
}
```

Comment: Translate please!

Comment: Seja bem vinda, isto é a resposta ou a pergunta? Recomendo que visite o tour, pois não somos um fórum e sim um Q&A: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Estou votando para encerrar essa pergunta como fora de escopo porque não é uma pergunta, mas sim uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Tentou ler a imagem direto como dados binários?

```
<?php
$filename = "image.png";
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Se for enviar via formulário, converta `$contents` para base64 usando `base64_encode($contents)`.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @FelipeDouradinho foi bacana. Mas, se você quer criar um array de bytes, você teria que fazer assim.

```
    $filename = "image.png";

    $file = fopen($filename, "rb");

    $tamanho_do_buffer = 4096;

    $array = array();

    while (! feof($file)) {

        $array[] = fread($file, $tamanho_do_buffer);
    }

    fclose($file);
```

Usar `file_get_contents` nesse caso não é recomendado. O `file_get_contents` retorna todo o conteúdo do arquivo. Já o `fopen` combinado com o `fread` define um tamanho específico de cara buffer que será aberto do arquivo, evitando assim uma sobrecarga na memória (dependendo, o seu script poderá gerar um erro se o uso da memória chegar ao limite definido no PHP)